# Antiderivative of $-\frac{1}{e^{3x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Solving, $\dfrac{-1}{e^{3x}}$ has different values by integrating using $u$ substitution if $3x$ is on the top or bottom, can someone see what I'm doing wrong? The top answer is negative while the bottom answer is positive.

> My work:
> $$\mathrm{d}x+e^{3x}\mathrm{d}y=0 \Longrightarrow\int\mathrm{d}y=\int-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{e^{3x}}\Longrightarrow y=-\int\frac{1}{e^u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{3}\Longrightarrow y=-\frac13\times\frac{1}{e^{3x}}$$
> With $u=3x$ and $\mathrm{d}u=3\mathrm{d}x$ or $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}3$.
>
> On the other hand:
> $$y=-\int e^{-3x}\mathrm{d}x\Longrightarrow -\int e^u\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{-3}\Longrightarrow \frac13e^{-3x}$$
> With $u=-3x$ and $\mathrm{d}u=-3\mathrm{d}x$ or $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{-3}$.

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Added, first time adding an image, but got it to work now

Comment: I don't think the third equality on the first line is correct. Why do you have $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: dx=du/3, the work for the first one is on the left in pink. Should I upload a neater one, I don't mind

Comment: Take a look at the first line, on the last passage. Now, what is the integral of 1/e^u, that is, the integral of e^(-u)? You already have a minus sign at the beginning, so...

Comment: The first answer negative while the second answer is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second computation is correct.

In the first one, there is a mistake in:

$$ y=-\int\frac{1}{e^u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{3}\Longrightarrow y=-\frac13\times\frac{1}{e^{3x}}$$

It should be:

$$y=-\int\frac{1}{e^u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{3}=-\frac13\int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{e^u}=-\frac13\int e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{3}e^{-u}=\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x}$$

The antiderivative of $e^u$ is $e^u$, but the antiderivative of $e^{-u}$ is $-e^{-u}$.

Notice that generally you can simplify such change of variable $u=ax$ by remembering that if $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, then $\frac1aF(ax)$ is an antiderivative of $f(ax)$.

---

Also, it should be obvious, but keep in mind that all these indefinite integrals should have a constant term added in the final result. Here it does not harm, but sometimes you end up with different nontrivial expressions that happen to differ by a *nonzero* constant. A usual example is

$$\int\frac{1}{\cosh x}\mathrm dx=2\arctan(e^x)+C$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\cosh x}\mathrm dx=2\arctan(\tanh\frac x2)+C$$

But

$$2\arctan(e^x)=2\arctan(\tanh\frac x2)+\frac{\pi}4$$

Comment: Ah makes sense, so to take the integral of 1/e^u, you MUST bring it to the top

Answer (score 0):

(Significant edits thanks to Jean-Claude's comment below.)

The major error is in the first one: $\int\frac{1}{e^u}du$ is not $\frac{1}{e^u}$, it's $-\frac{1}{e^u}$. $\int e^udu$ is the straightforward one - in order to use it for $\frac{1}{e^u}$, you'd have to use another $u$-substitution, like the one you did in the second version.

Comment: The second one looks correct to me.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Quite right - I was mistaken about what OP was trying to integrate. Thanks for pointing it out.